# Get current location in JS/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, geolocation, google-geolocation

I am trying to get current location (with address, not only lat, long),  But i am stuck that how to get?
Here is the code:

```
<button onclick="getLocation()">Click Me</button>
<div id="address"></div>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("address");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>
```

It's returning only latitude and longitude. But i need full address like Model town 30-A, Lahore or something like this address.
Here is the site which has this kind of functionality: https://gps-coordinates.org/my-location.php.
**To check, open this link and see in the Address input.**

Please help me. How can i get current address?

Comment: Use Google's Reverse Geolocation API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse. Note that this will not be 100% accurate on a mobile device, and will just about give you a region/country on a desktop PC, if you're lucky.

Comment: No, see the example link who works like same as i want. But i don't need these all functionalities. I just need current full address not only lat, long.

Comment: Yes, but unless you have all the lookup data for every address in the world by its lat/lng values, it's not going to work. This is why you need the Google API.

Comment: but google developers api is not free

Comment: That's correct. I don't believe there are any free reverse geolocation API services which are free, or at least not severely rate limited (in the region of 10 requests/day).

Comment: The link i've attached above, are they using paid service or free?

Comment: Check the source. They are using Apple Mapkit https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkitjs. It free, although is rate limited.

Comment: means, i can't get current full address

Comment: So long as you have a lat/lng position, then yes you can https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkitjs/mapkit/geocoder